# ef6 database migrations change table name

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

I am using EF6 code first and database migrations to keep my new database up do date.
I wanted to change the name of one of the database tables from "contacts" to "contact".

So in EF I change the name of the class and in the customised DBContext class I rename Contacts to Contact so it is now showing;

```
public DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
```

However I run the database migrations with Update-Database -Verbose -Force and no change is made.
To find out what is going on I put a new field in, and it tries to update the Contacts table rather than Contact which it needs to create.
So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Try removing Pluralizing:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: I have just found the answer - a different one - where I use the table attribute; [Table("Contact")] in front of the class. However I think your answer would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which is to use the following attribute in from of the class declaration;

```
[Table("Contact")]
```